# tips of easy to start tutorials/guides

Tags: micropython

I want to try out Micrpopython (as a beginner) and I want some tips for some easy tutorials to get started. What I have in mind of something fun, to begin with, would be a temperature sensor that activates a LED light when a certain temperature is exceeded (or other type of warning).

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

A good start will be through the official [doc](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/), They provided you with all the information needed to use it, whether you want to use esp32 or esp8266 and if you need more information about coding or anything else you can visit GitHub [here](https://github.com/micropython/micropython), there's also a lot of courses on Udemy if you want, but for me, GitHub was great.